# Searching for Socket hosts and displaying their IP Addresses Python

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, server

I'm creating a local client-server game on Python using sockets where a server is hosted on the local network and the clients on the network can connect to the server if they have the server's IP address. It's not a dedicated server so it just runs on another thread on a client's computer. Currently, the client has to manually enter the IP address of the server to connect to it. I want the client to be able to search the network for avaialble servers join, but i'm not sure how to get the server to broadcast it's availability.

This is the server-side script:

```
totalConnections = 0
port = 5555
host=socket.gethostname()
IP = socket.gethostbyname(host) #this just fetches the computer's IP address so the server can use it
server = IP
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    s.bind((server, port))
except socket.error as e:
    str(e)

s.listen(2)
print("Waiting for a connection, Server Started")

while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print("Connected to:", addr)
    totalConnections += 1

    start_new_thread(threaded_client, (conn, currentPlayer))
    currentPlayer += 1 

def threaded_client(conn, player):

    conn.send(pickle.dumps(all_data[player])) # sends player data to client
    While True:
        conn.sendall(pickle.dumps(reply))
```

This is the client-side:

```
class Network:
def __init__(self,ip):
    self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.server = ip
    self.port = 5555
    self.addr = (self.server, self.port)
    self.p = self.connect()

def getP(self):
    return self.p

def connect(self):
    try:
        self.client.connect(self.addr)
        return pickle.loads(self.client.recv(2048*3))
    except:
        pass

def send(self, data):
    try:
        self.client.send(pickle.dumps(data))
        return pickle.loads(self.client.recv(2048*3))
    except socket.error as e:
        print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution using multicasting on a specific UDP port where all the clients connect to so the data can be shared amongst them : https://pymotw.com/2/socket/multicast.html